# How to loop listbox.FindString() for each item

Tags: c#, search, loops, listbox

I am stuck trying to find a way to loop `listbox.FindString()` for each item to search through a listbox of items. Just an example:

Example Code:

```
string myString = "hi";

int index = listBox1.FindString(myString, -1);

if (index != -1) {
    listBox1.SetSelected(index, true);
    MessageBox.Show("Found the item \"" + myString + "\" at index: " + index);
}
```

Comment: One of two things is happening: I'm misunderstanding your question (very likely), or you are misunderstanding how FindString works. It's already looping through each item of the listbox and searching for what you are looking for. It doesn't need to be in a loop to work. Are you trying to set up a loop to go through multiple listboxes?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I wanted it to continue looking after it found its first result, rather than stopping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
int index = ListBox.NoMatches;
while ((index = listBox1.FindString(myString, index)) != ListBox.NoMatches)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found the item \"" + myString + "\" at index: " + index);
}
```